# Cleaning up tennis ball as simple as possible

Tags: tennis, equipment, maintenance, beach-tennis

Just brought some tennis balls (some normal, some beach) and play until dirty.

So, how do I get it clean up with the least damage done to the tennis balls?

(Had done some research online and it was mention that soaking in water with detergent for 30 minutes or clean them using a toothbrush and toothpaste.)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to clean up tennis ball is with  detergent, pour the tennis balls into the container with the detergent and let them soak for 30 minutes.

But if you don't want to use this, I have found other technique that can be useful for you:

**Washing Machine**

1. Adjust the machine to work with water at cold temperature. Using hot water can cause the rubber of the balls to deform or melt.
2. Don't let the washer go through the spin cycle with the tennis balls. Allowing this to happen can end up deforming the balls and also causing damage to the washer.
3. Wash the balls with the same liquid detergent you use for washing clothes. Also, try to use approximately the same amount used to wash a small amount of clothing.
4. When the tennis balls are clean, set them to dry for about ten minutes in the dryer set at the lowest possible temperature. In addition, you can also put them to dry outdoors.